# multi-pom in intellijIDEA. Error adding module to project: null

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I wanted to make a multi-pom project in Intellij (2020.3.4). In one Maven project, I right-click ->New -> Module -> Maven. select parent to "my project". However, even if parent is not specified, I get the error: **Error adding module to project: null**. (at the same time, it adds a regular folder with the module name and an empty pom.xml inside) (This happens with any archetype). I didn't find any solutions on the Internet at all. Only downgrade to the old version of Intellij IDEA and that solution was published 10 years ago. Tell me what is the problem? Or what to do? Does not work only with "Maven". With "Java" and "Spring Inizializr" it works.

**idea.log**

```
2022-03-23 15:54:05,382 [81624884]   WARN - il.projectWizard.ModuleBuilder -  
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1011)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1006)
    at java.base/java.util.Properties.put(Properties.java:1340)
    at java.base/java.util.Properties.setProperty(Properties.java:228)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.utils.MavenUtil.runOrApplyMavenProjectFileTemplate(MavenUtil.java:384)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.utils.MavenUtil.runOrApplyMavenProjectFileTemplate(MavenUtil.java:341)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.wizards.MavenModuleBuilderHelper.lambda$configure$0(MavenModuleBuilderHelper.java:85)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl$2.run(WriteCommandAction.java:122)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.RunResult.run(RunResult.java:35)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$performWriteCommandAction$1(WriteCommandAction.java:253)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1000)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$performWriteCommandAction$2(WriteCommandAction.java:252)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$doExecuteCommand$4(WriteCommandAction.java:310)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:220)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:187)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.doExecuteCommand(WriteCommandAction.java:312)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.performWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:251)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.execute(WriteCommandAction.java:232)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl.compute(WriteCommandAction.java:124)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.wizards.MavenModuleBuilderHelper.configure(MavenModuleBuilderHelper.java:79)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.wizards.AbstractMavenModuleBuilder.lambda$setupRootModel$0(AbstractMavenModuleBuilder.java:77)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.utils.MavenUtil.runDumbAware(MavenUtil.java:211)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.utils.MavenUtil.runWhenInitialized(MavenUtil.java:231)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.wizards.AbstractMavenModuleBuilder.setupRootModel(AbstractMavenModuleBuilder.java:70)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.ModuleBuilder.setupModule(ModuleBuilder.java:260)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.ModuleBuilder.createModule(ModuleBuilder.java:253)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.ModuleBuilder.createAndCommitIfNeeded(ModuleBuilder.java:292)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.ModuleBuilder.lambda$commitModule$4(ModuleBuilder.java:338)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteActionWithClass(ApplicationImpl.java:988)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1014)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.ModuleBuilder.commitModule(ModuleBuilder.java:337)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ui.configuration.actions.NewModuleAction.createModuleFromWizard(NewModuleAction.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ui.configuration.actions.NewModuleAction.actionPerformed(NewModuleAction.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:281)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:310)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:286)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:77)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:299)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:110)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:95)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:110)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:514)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:544)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6652)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3345)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6417)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5027)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4859)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4859)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:778)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:976)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:911)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:840)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:454)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:773)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:453)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:822)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:507)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
2022-03-23 15:54:05,981 [81625483]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Cannot reconnect. 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot reconnect.
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:82)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper.getArchetypes(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:143)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndicesManager.getArchetypes(MavenIndicesManager.java:337)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.wizards.MavenArchetypesStep.lambda$updateArchetypesList$3(MavenArchetypesStep.java:223)
    at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:20)
    at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:11)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.call(ApplicationImpl.java:270)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:623)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:209)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:132)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:217)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:162)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy146.createIndexer(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.invokeRemote(RemoteUtil.java:150)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.access$400(RemoteUtil.java:21)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$1.lambda$invoke$0(RemoteUtil.java:134)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ClassLoaderUtil.computeWithClassLoader(ClassLoaderUtil.java:31)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.executeWithClassLoader(RemoteUtil.java:202)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$1.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:134)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy146.createIndexer(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerConnectorImpl.createIndexer(MavenServerConnectorImpl.java:197)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager$4.create(MavenServerManager.java:381)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager$4.create(MavenServerManager.java:377)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.getOrCreateWrappee(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper.lambda$getArchetypes$6(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:143)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:76)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:101)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:558)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:454)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:231)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteServer$1.createSocket(RemoteServer.java:122)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:617)
    ... 37 more
2022-03-23 15:54:05,981 [81625483]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.4  Build #IU-203.8084.24 
2022-03-23 15:54:05,981 [81625483]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - JDK: 11.0.10; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o. 
2022-03-23 15:54:05,981 [81625483]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - OS: Windows 10 
2022-03-23 15:54:05,981 [81625483]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Last Action: NewModuleInGroup 
2022-03-23 15:54:06,580 [81626082]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 1922ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2022-03-23 15:54:06,580 [81626082]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 0 files to index 
2022-03-23 15:54:06,580 [81626082]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 1922ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2022-03-23 15:54:06,595 [81626097]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 0 files to index 
2022-03-23 15:54:08,524 [81628026]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appFileTypeManager took 16 ms
```

Comment: May you share a more detailed error from the idea.log file? Like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-215152#focus=Comments-27-3507751.0-0

Comment: sorry, i added to the question

Comment: According to the log, IDE cannot communicate with Maven daemon to apply Maven project template. Do you have a firewall which may prevent localhost connections for the IDE?

Comment: Same case caused by the firewall: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-239928

Answer (score 4):

In Intellij goto File -> Project Structure -> Project SDK -> [Select Your Installed SDK Version] -> Ok

And try to add the new module, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try next things:

1. Go to File-Project Structure-Project. Check SDK and Language level. Make it the same if it's not. For example 17.
2. Then go to Modules. Sources-Language level and Dependencies-Module SDK must be as Project SDK (e.g. 17). All your next modules should also be 17.
3. Then go to SDKs just to check that the required SDK (17) is present in the list.
4. Then go to File-Settings-Build, Execution, Deployment-Compiler-Java Compiler. For all modules Taget bytecode version should be 17.
5. In your pom.xml <java.version> should also be as SDK version (17).

After you do all this steps restart IntelliJ IDEA and then check everything again step by step. All SDKs, Languages and versions should be like in your project (17).

And finally, to create a general Maven module, go to the New Module (not to Maven archetype). In New Module menu check Build system, it's should be Maven. Also check JDK (17).

I hope it will help. Good luck!